# in javascript, how to always keep the spinner in the center of current screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My following code can't make the spinner always show up in the center of the screen. Could anyone please help me?

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.id="create";
div.style.top="50%";
div.style.left="30%";
div.style.width = "100px";
div.style.height = "100px";
div.style.background = "white";
div.style.color = "blue";
div.innerHTML = "please wait while your request is processed.";
div.style.zIndex="5";
div.position="fixed";
div.style.margintop="-9em"; 
div.style.marginleft="-15em";  
document.getElementById('center').appendChild(div);
ams.showSpinner( {

    element: $('create'),
    opacity: 0.3,
    duration: 0.3
 } );
```

Comment: How is it currently displaying with this code?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend this approach:

JS:

```
$("<div/>", {
    id: 'create',
    text: 'Please wait while your request is processed.'
}).appendTo('#center');
ams.showSpinner({
    element: $('create'),
    opacity: 0.3,
    duration: 0.3
});
```

CSS:

```
#create{
    background: white;
    color: blue;
    position:absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    z-index: 5;
    margin: -50px 0 0 -50px;
}
```

`#create` is `50%` from the top and 50% from the `left` but the negative margin value is half the width/height of itself so it's positioned in the center.

I only added the extra jQuery code to make it more readable, it's fine to use this instead:

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.id = "create";
div.innerHTML = "please wait while your request is processed.";
document.getElementById('center').appendChild(div);
ams.showSpinner({
    element: $('create'),
    opacity: 0.3,
    duration: 0.3
});
```